# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: Tourism.addedOffer index: *id* dup key: { _id: "617b6e76110c116302d9afdd" }

Comment: welcome to SO. Go through the link to understand how to ask question with minimal reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Imagine you are the person answering this question... Help others help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.